# Using OAuth2 flow within Google Script Library is returning 'Redirect or Missing URI'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, smartsheet-api

I am writing a custom google scripts library for use within multiple google sheets. It uses the [Google Script OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) to manage the OAuth flow with the [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/). Unfortunately it is returning 'Redirect URI missing or invalid'.

I had the OAuth2 flow working well in a single spreadsheet script, but it stopped working when I moved the code into a library.

I ***DID*** update the redirect URI within Smartsheet's developer menu and I verified that the URI returned from .getRedirectUri() was the one associated with my app within Smartsheet's app registration.

The other aspects of the code within the library are working well, and give me high confidence that it is still working as it did when it was tied to a sheet.

My goal with the library is that it can be used from multiple sheets to access the Smartsheet API, and thereby prevent me from creating a unique app (with unique redirect URI) within the Smartsheet developer menu for each sheet that might ever use this code.

Is this possible? What might I be doing wrong that it doesn't like the redirect URI?

Comment: When you reach the page where you see the 'Redirect URI missing or invalid' message, does the value for the redirect_uri query string param in the URL match the value returned from .getRedirectUri()?

Answer (score 0):

When developing a library it is best to be agnostic to the source of token. A common design pattern is to have the user pass in a function that your library calls to get a token. This allows the user to choose how and where the OAuth workflow is implemented.

myLibrary.gs

```
var tokenService_ = function(){return null};

function setTokenService(tokenService){
  tokenService_ = tokenService
}

//some hypothetical function in your library
function getData(options){
  return fetchFromAPI(options,tokenService_());
}
```

userCode.gs

```
function requestData(){
  myLibrary.setTokenService(function(){ return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()});
  var data = myLibrary.getData("foo");
}
```